# How to upload image in php with other it's information

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am new with php and I tried this example to upload file in php

http://phppot.com/php/mysql-blob-using-php/

With following form:

```
<form name="frmImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="frmImageUpload">
    <label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
    <input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

Actually i want to add one more input with type text. So form will become:

```
<form name="frmImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="frmImageUpload">
    <label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
    <input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" />
    <input type="text" name="imageinfo"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

and script to upload file is:

```
<?php
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        //$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

        $l=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password","test");
        //mysql_select_db ("test");
        $imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
        $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO output_images(imageType ,imageData)
        VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')";
        $current_id = mysqli_query($l,$sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysql_error());
        if(isset($current_id)) {
            header('Location: listImages.php');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I notice `BLOB` as a tag. Now, what's the problem with your code, are you checking for errors? My guess is, your db insert is failing because of the column type and you're not handling the query the way it should be handled.

Comment: Actually this code works fine but i want to add one more input text see second form and i don't know how to deal with it like in java we can check form data

Comment: this `mysql_error()` doesn't help you. it should read as `mysqli_error($l)`

Comment: then just add a POST array then and assign a variable to it. *Done like dinner*

Answer (score 0):

File uploads come through $_FILES. Everything else comes through $_POST, so you can just query `$POST['imageinfo']`